# How to find mean values of variables $x$ and $y$ in functions of the form $f(x)=g(y)$?

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion, means

Suppose I have a function of the form $f(x) = g(y)$? Then how am I supposed to find the mean values of $x$ or $y$?

I have the knowledge to find mean values of functions of the form $y=f(x)$ using the area under the curve but not more than that.

Although I am more interested in a generalized solution, currently I am stuck with a function of the form

$$y=\frac{kx^3}{e^{mx} -1} $$

Where $k$ and $m$ are constants.
And I am interested in the mean value of $x$ i. e. $<x>$.
$$ x  \in   (0, \infty) $$
$$ y   \in  (0, 1.248 \times 10^{-26}] $$
So far, I've tried to somehow represent the above function in the form of $x=f(y)$, but to no success. Even after using the McLaurin series expansion, I couldn't do it. It always translates to the form :
$f(x) = g(y)$?

Comment: What is the domain of the function that you want to find the mean of?

Comment: @eatfood! Although I have added the domain, like I said, I am more interested in a generalized solution so that I don't have to get stuck with a similar situation again.

Comment: @eatfood , The domain is x>0. Can you please be kind enough to help me with this?

Comment: I don't have much of a clue actually...I also tried to write $x$ in terms of $y$ but its not working.